# How to export array data through node addon

Tags: c++, node.js, node.js-addon

I'm using node 0.12.x, I want to return some array data from node addon written by c++

```
Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
MyObject* obj = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<MyObject>(args.Holder());
obj->value_ += 1;
args.GetReturnValue().Set(Number::New(isolate, obj->value_));
```

This is a sample for returning Number data.

Comment: I'd expand on this question if I were you. I don't even know what to ask for in further information.

Answer (score 3):

```
using namespace v8;
```

Create an array:

```
Local<Array> myArray = Array::New(isolate);
```

You can then create objects with properties (or just integers) and push them into the array:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    Local<Object> obj = Object::New(isolate);
    obj->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "tag1"), "test");
    myArray->Set(i, obj);
 }

 args.GetReturnValue().Set(myArray);
```

If you're writing native code for node.js I highly recommend using nan:
https://github.com/nodejs/nan